# The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 661 and earlier

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am new in asp.net c# coding and I created a simple website connected to the database using visual studio express 2013. After I finished making the website I tried uploading the files on a hosting website, everything works fine but when I tried uploading the `database.mdf` file and then attach it, I got this error message:

> Error attaching database. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The database 'my_Database' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 661 and earlier.

I tried changing SQL Server instance name from `(LocalDB)\v11.0` to SQL Server 2008 but it didn't work.

The hosting site I am using is [aspspider.com](http://www.aspspider.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the `database.mdf` file that you are using was created with Sql Server 2012, whereas your hosting provider only has Sql Server 2008 installed.

You need to either recreated `database.mdf` locally with Sql Server 2008, or see if your hosting provider can upgrade you to Sql Server 2012.

Looking at aspspider, they only seem to provide free hosting with Microsoft Sql Server 2008 Express Edition. You can download a copy of it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695).  Install this locally, use it from your app, and then upload it to the hosting provider.

Comment: how can I recreat database.mdf locally with Sql Server 2008 ?